# Why is this relation a function?

Tags: functions, relations

> I need to determine whether or not the relation  $\{ (a^2,a) | a \in \Bbb {R}, a \geq 0\}$ is a function from $\Bbb {R}$ to $\Bbb {R}$.

I think that it is a function. But I don't know how to justify my reasoning besides saying that $a^2$ can only map to $a$. 4 Only maps to 2, 9 only maps to 3

Comment: It is not a function...draw a picture.

Comment: But since $a \geq 0$ wouldn't 4 only map to 2 then?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a function?

Comment: You are right; because the two "roots" of $a^2$ are $a$ and $-a$, if we "cut-off" the negative numbers (by the clause : $a \ge 0$ in the defining condition of the relation) what is left is only the *positive* root of $a^2$. Thus the "functionality" condition for a *relation* $xRy$ (i.e. : if $y_1 \ne y_2$, then $x_1 \ne x_2, with $x_1Ry_1, x_2Ry_2$) applies.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $a^2$ gets mapped to $a$, what does $x$ get mapped to, where $x$ is any nonnegative real number? If there's a unique answer, then you have a function. Otherwise, it is not a function.